# python ffmpeg subprocess not working on heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, video, ffmpeg

I've made a bot that deals with gif files and I tried uploading it on heroku.

So I've installed this buildpack https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest

And I run this code as a subprocess:

```
id_name = "je4d" (is actually randomized bc it downloads different gifs)
path = "./media/%s.gif" % (id_name)
subprocess.run('ffmpeg -y -ignore_loop 0 -i %s -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -t 15 %s' % (path, path.replace(".gif", ".mp4")), shell=True)
```

So if I run this on my computer, it will transform je4d.gif into an .mp4 and it works fine

If I try to test ffmpeg on heroku by doing `heroku run bash`
and then inputing the command `ffmpeg -y -ignore_loop 0 -i ./media/je4d.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -t 15 ./media/je4d.mp4`
It also works fine and makes a .mp4

However if I run the code on heroku from python it does this:
`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -y -i ./media/3s1m8cw09sl11.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" ./media/3s1m8cw09sl11.mp4': 'ffmpeg -y -i ./media/3s1m8cw09sl11.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" ./media/3s1m8cw09sl11.mp4'`

So I thought maybe there's an error with the download, so I change path to a static file on the server, and it still gives me the same error.
Any tips?

Comment: If you change your `subprocess.run()` argument from a single string into a list, e.g. something like `subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-ignore_loop', '0', '-i', path, '-movflags', 'faststart', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-vf', '"scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"', '-t', '15', path.replace(".gif", ".mp4")'], shell=True)`, does it work?

Comment: Hey @Chris I just tried this (I tried doing this before but I never quite understood how to do it right), it does seem to make a path.mp4 but it's borken (0kb), I tried running the same ffmpeg code on my cmd and it made a 85kb .mp4 so there's something wrong

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be, but another factor is that Heroku's filesystem is only designed to be used as a short-term scratchpad. If you get this working, make sure you don't rely on those files being stored long-term.

Comment: Yes it downloads the files from different sources, ffmpeg thems up, uploads them and then deletes them automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for conversion on Heroku is using a pure python wrapper of FFmpeg.
Like [ffmpy](https://ffmpy.readthedocs.io).
Here's an example:

**first:**

```
pip install ffmpy
```

then you can use it like:

```
from ffmpy import FFmpeg
ff = FFmpeg(
    inputs={'je4d.gif': None},
    outputs={'je4d.mp4': None}
    )
ff.run()
```